# Trying to delete a table view row in an NSUserdefault array

Tags: ios, ios5

I am trying to delete a row int the table view and after that saving the updated table view to an array in NSUserdefault. It looks like this:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 

 commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle

  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSMutableArray *stringsArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"history"];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *history = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[prefs objectForKey:@"history"]];    
 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

 NSUInteger count = [stringsArray count];


 if (row < count) {



    [stringsArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];


  [prefs setObject:history forKey:@"history"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [tableView reloadData]; 

    NSLog(@"tabort %d", row);
    NSLog(@"tabort %d", count);    
    NSLog(@"tabort %@", stringsArray);

    }

    }
```

When I run it I can delete one row but it does not get saved and when I try to delete the next row it craches with the following message:

> 2012-04-15 11:02:58.704 test220[88546:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to
>   immutable object'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the line:

```
NSMutableArray *stringsArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"history"];
```

to:

```
NSMutableArray *stringsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"history"]];
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it does not crash any more, but it still does not save to NSUserdefaults

Comment: That is because you aren't doing anything with the "history" instance. Try to organize the flow - Take everything you need from NSUserDefaults, manipulate the data and at the end store it and synchronize it back. Check the data in your debugger right before it gets synced